# How to assign a variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I tried to assign to variable and copy to textarea using jquery but i cant able to do it, can any one help me

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5" 
      async></script> 
 <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com" data-width="500"></div>


<button id="copy">Copy Text</button><br />
<textarea id="paste"></textarea>

$("#copy").click(function() { 
    $val = '<div id="fb-root"></div>';
 $val = $val +  '<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5" async></script>';
$val = $val + '<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com" data-width="500"></div>';
    $("#paste").val($val);
});
```

Comment: Are you really just putting your JavaScript code alongside your HTML? It should be inside of a `<script>` element. Also, you need to include the jQuery library, which you haven't done. Or did you copy this from the HTML and JavaScript sections of a JSFiddle?

Comment: In javascript you have to use a variable declaration : ```let```, ```var```, ```const``` when declaring a variable. Also as mentioned, your js should be inside ```<script></script>``` tags

Comment: @WilomGfx Only in strict mode. Regardless, though, that is not at all why the OP's code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a variable in jQuery is no different than vanilla:

```
var myVariable = 'my value';
```

The `$` turns things, such as variables, into jQuery objects, which allow you to perform jQuery actions on them. The `$` is also used in PHP to indicate a variable.

Comment: ```var $val = 'value'``` is also valid. But indeed javascript you have to use a variable declaration : let, var, const when declaring a variable.

Comment: @WilomGfx In non-strict mode, assigning to undeclared variables treats them as implicit globals and does not require a declaration (which is not to say this is a *good* programming practice, but it is a syntactically and semantically valid way to write code.)